# ¿cómo puedo solucionar "could not connect to mysql with the given password"?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench, mysqldb

[image: Intento instalar MySQL y en esta sección no me deja avanzar para nada.]

Ya tenía anteriormente MySQL instalado pero lo tuve que borrar, no estoy seguro si deba poner la contraseña anterior pero si ese es el caso, la olvidé.

Comment: Prueba dejando el password en blanco (por lo general la clave por defecto es en blanco para el usuario `root`). Si no funciona, puedes optar por editar el archivo de configuración de MySQL.

Comment: Seguramente es la ultima contraseña que tenías en la cuenta. La podes recuperar en https://www.mysql.com/ yendo a "Login" > "¿Necesitas Ayuda?" > "I forgot my password" e ingresar el mail de la cuenta